# Is it possible to underflow a floating point addition in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point

I was looking at the Intel Processor manual, volumen 2A, pages 3.266-3.268 and it states that the FADD operation may produce #U (Underflow) exception.
The reasoning is that result will be to small to be properly represented in DST.

I wondering if addition underflow is possible on C++ using native datatypes (float, double, long double) or if the language wrapping of the datatype makes the addition operation safe on regards of underflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a positive and a negative number that are very close to each other, producing a [denormal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number), then the underflow flag is set (if underflow exception is not masked). Link to intel article [denormals and underflow](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/x87-and-sse-floating-point-assists-in-ia-32-flush-to-zero-ftz-and-denormals-are-zero-daz).

Example code (using Microsoft compiler):

```
    double a,b,c;
    a =  2.2250738585072019e-308;
    b = -2.2250738585072014e-308;
    c = a + b;   /* c is denormal */
    printf("%28.16le %016llx\n", a, a);
    printf("%28.16le %016llx\n", b, b);
    printf("%28.16le %016llx\n", c, c);
    if ( std::fpclassify( c ) == FP_SUBNORMAL ) printf("c is DENORMAL");
```

To enable (unmask) the underflow exception (Microsoft compiler):

```
    short fcw; /* floating point control word - 16 bit */
    /* enable underflow exception */
    __asm{
        fnstcw  fcw
        and     fcw,0ffefh
        fldcw   fcw
    }
```

Comment: Oh, you are right, I was thinking about how to produce it with small numbers, but if numbers are similar and far from 0, it may be easy. If you post an example can accept your answer.

Comment: It is easy to obtain a subnormal number as the sum of two normal numbers. Enough bits among the most significant bits simply need to cancel out. Since there are 53 significant digits in double-precision, subnormal results can be obtained as the sum of two well-chosen numbers up to 2^52 * DBL_MIN (give or take a factor of two).

Comment: @PascalCuoq Nice reference, I was thinking in underflow being always working as in FTZ mode, while there is indeed other possibilities to be considered.

Answer (score 2):

An underflow condition occurs when the result of the computation is a denormal (subnormal) number. This is formally called *gradual underflow* (as opposed to producing zero). So by adding almost any two denormal numbers, an underflow will occur as long as the result is also a denormal number. For example:

```
pow(2.0, -1074.0) + pow(2.0, -1073.0)
```

All operands here are of type **double**.

Intel certainly was referring to gradual underflow. However considering *abrupt underflow*, then it's not possible by using only addition and/or subtraction.